# MySQL SELECTING data by USERNAME and FOLLOWING tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables,

FEED - USERS - FOLLOWING

I am trying to display a feed where either `USERNAME = $_SESSION[username]` OR if the currently logged in user is following someone in the FOLLOWING table

Here is my current query that selects all from feed based just on USERNAME and NOT including FOLLOWING table

```
SELECT feed.id, feed.username, feed.status, feed.timestamp, users.image 
FROM feed,users 
AND users.username = '$username'
ORDER BY feed.id DESC
```

Table design:

[image]

So how do I make this query include anyone from the FOLLOWING table?

```
TABLES:
--
-- Table structure for table `feed`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feed` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `following`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `following` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `following` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isfollowing` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
  `profile_background` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_background.png',
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `went_to_school` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `worked_at` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lives_in` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `from_originally` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a',
  `show_email` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;
```

Comment: You should be absolutely sure things like `$username` are escaped in your query or you could be in for bad times. Also why are you using the user name as a key here? It really should be based on something more immutable like ID if you're following proper database normalization practices. Using username exposes you to the risks of someone "inheriting" data from an account that was deleted if they choose the same name.

Comment: My particular system doesnt allow username changes so a user will not be prone to inheritance. The $username var is escape in the php var so we are good there as well. Bad practice? Yes. I just got used to doing it in such a way :(

Comment: It doesn't allow it *today* but you can't say for sure that won't happen in the future. Hopefully you can fix this before it becomes a huge issue. As a plus, because of their size ID-based indexes are generally way faster and more scalable.

Comment: By the way, what you need here is a `JOIN` to combine the tables.

Comment: Could you throw up a small example with the above query? I am kind of new to JOINing tables. Thanks man.

Comment: I can't read your microscopic screenshot. A text-based version of the schema would be a lot easier to deal with, like the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea here is to `JOIN` in the `following` table:

```
 SELECT feeds.*
   FROM feeds
   LEFT JOIN following ON following.following=feeds.username
   WHERE feeds.username=? OR following.username=?
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is a way of saying "combine A with B if there's a match, otherwise leave B as all NULL values". There's other types that do different things.

Note that this is *extremely* clunky using usernames as keys. I'd strongly encourage you to migrate to an ID based system as soon as possible.

You should also stay away from MyISAM tables, they don't support transactions and have no journal. A simple server crash can utterly trash the table beyond repair. InnoDB is significantly more robust and should be used whenever possible. In MySQL 5.7 there's rarely a reason to use MyISAM at all.

Comment: I need to obtain the user profile data (which is stored in users table) also.

This doesn't account for unique folllowing (for instance if username1 is following 3 people, it will list 3 peoples * 3)

Comment: You can join that in if you need to, but this will make your query increasingly slow. Why not just retrieve user data in a second query?

Comment: I was told one query is always better. Maybe I'm wrong? :( Regardless on user_profile data, how would I get DISTINCT rows from an LEFT JOIN?

Comment: One query can be better, but you need to evaluate it on a case by case basis. If you have a lot of user data you're pulling out then a second query will send the data once per user, not once per post. That could be significantly less data.

Comment: Here's what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/svwXHm2.png - its showing 1 feed post 3 times based on 3 followers

Comment: It shouldn't be doing a cross product unless you're following multiple instances of the same person. A `UNIQUE` index on `username,following` would fix that.

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I came up with based on your query:
SELECT DISTINCT feed.*
                                            FROM feed
                                            LEFT JOIN following ON following.following=feed.username
                                            WHERE feed.username='$username' OR following.username='$username'
                                            ORDER BY feed.id DESC

Comment: That's the right idea. Do try and use prepared statements for those queries. `?` or `:username` is significantly safer than having actual strings in your statement.

Comment: Also if you've got skype id love to learn some things from you skype: lukecode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167801/how-to-order-message-groups-messages-just-like-imessage